# Weight Painting: How to set weight for part of mesh for only one vertex group?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

My problem is that I use *Auto-weight* when connecting armature to mesh. This causes lots of unwanted weighting on close proximity parts.

Sometimes I want certain parts to be weighted by only on one vertex group. Say a bag (mesh) must only be connected to the hip (vertex group) and shouldn't have weight from other vertex groups.

Is there a way to quickly define the weight of the mesh for only one vertex group without going into other groups and removing the selected mesh?

**OR**

Is there a way to unweight (weight 0) on all the vertex groups save one?

Comment: if you select those vertices, then on the right of the vertex groups list, there's a dropdown menu (down arrow) > Remove From All Groups, is it what you want?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select those vertices, then on the right of the *Vertex Groups* list, there's a dropdown menu (down arrow) > *Remove From All Groups*.